# Acess public jenkins docker

Tags: jenkins, debian, virtualhost, debian-stretch

I am having a debian 9 server, which is having a public ip: 37.187.6.XXX, I also  access my webserver using a domain name http://www.myweb.com

On this Debian server installed a jenkins docker:

```
# docker run -d -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:z -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name myjenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

How can i access to this docker jenkins docker from public ?

I don' t know if it would help:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myweb.com
    ServerName myweb.com
    ServerAlias www.dev2one.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myweb.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When i am trying to access the url: http://37.187.6.XXX:8080/ nothing is showing

thanks for helping

---

edit 1

I guess that the 8080 port is closed:

```
root@ns3371000:/# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      570/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5801/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      570/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16603/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2172/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      21054/vsftpd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      570/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5801/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      570/named
```

Comment: Have your opened the port on your router?

Comment: Hi @zero298, I installed the server by default

Answer (score 0):

According to your **netstat -plnt** :

- 8080 port is not used. This has nothing to do with open or closed ports.
- Maybe your application (dockerized jenkins) has not started correctly.

  - Could you view docker logs : **docker logs myjenkins**
- Maybe your application (dockerized jenkins) uses another port like **80**

  - Could you exec **netstat -plnt** inside of your docker container to detect what is the true port?
- If ports are correct, try this :

  - curl http://localhost:8080
  - curl http://localhost:80

  If one of them returns an html, that would be your port to use with  http://37.187.6.XXX:...